# How to insert swift interpolation in json vapor return message?

Tags: json, swift, vapor

Using Vapor for testing json message :

```
        get("post") { req in
        guard let name = req.data["name"]?.string else {
            throw Abort.badRequest
        }

        return try JSON(json: [
            "message": "Hello, \(name)!"
            ])
    }
```

I get this error :

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected dictionary value type 'JSON'

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Either don't use a String in `JSON(json:)` or don't use `JSON(json:)` if you need to use a String. `JSON(json:)` expects a JSON object, not a JSON string.

Comment: @Moritz thanks, I actually managed to solve the issue JSON(node:) is still works although it's not on completion. so make a JSON Object is real help.